# How to detect charset of text?

Tags: c#, php, diacritics

I have a text with diacritic characters that are displayed bad, like this: ¤ or ˇ or ˘. I don't know what charset the text was. Is there any easy way to figure it out? It would be nice if there is some online charset detector or maybe charset conversion previewer? I think about a application that would show me how some specific diacritic characters look like malformed in all available encodings so i would be able to track the one that fits into the chars i have in the text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it have to be C# or PHP?

Comment: It can be C#, PHP, or any application i can run on Windows or website tool.

Comment: Where are you getting your text from? A file on disk?

Comment: From a file, but it lacks encoding info

Comment: but i need solution that works for text from clipboard (not direct, i can just paste it into C# or PHP code)

Comment: Could you paste a sample from your file as part of the question?

Comment: Detecting charset is NEVER 100% accurate. I think the best you can do is about 90% accuracy. This is just a nature of encoding, some valid chars overlap in different charsets.

Comment: Dmitri, read the question again; it's not about automagically detecting a character set but manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows PowerShell:

```
$bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes('some file.txt')
[Text.Encoding]::GetEncodings() |
  %{
    $_|Add-Member -pass Noteproperty Text ($_.GetEncoding().GetString($bytes))
  } | fl Name,Codepage,Text
```

Adjust the path to the file and browse the results until you see something that looks correct ;-)

This simply iterates through all encodings that are known to .NET and converts the text into a string using the respective encoding.

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
foreach (EncodingInfo encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings())
    using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream, encodingInfo.GetEncoding(), false))
        textBox1.Text += encodingInfo.DisplayName + ":\t " + reader.ReadToEnd() + "\r\n";
```

where `textBox1` is a large multiline `TextBox` (or any other suitable control).

Some caveats I learnt:

1. Console applications do not support Unicode by default.
2. [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369.aspx) attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks, even when another encoding is explicitly specified. The only way to suppress this is through the [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/akzyzwh9.aspx) constructor overload which allows one to suppress looking for byte order marks.

Comment: and how to do this from clipboard?

Comment: I would suggest using the file-based approach (using the _original_ file). Decoding is a lossy operation when the incorrect encoding is used.